# Jquery does not apply effect when input arrives at value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery does not apply effect when input arrives at value with buttons

I have this form where the user can insert a quantity in an input field. It works when you insert the numbers manually and I want it to work with buttons too, but i just can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```js
$('.qty').blur(function(){
    tmpval = $(this).val();
    if(tmpval == '50') {
        $('.copo50').addClass('copocheck');

    } else {

        $('.copo50').removeClass('copocheck');
    }

    if ((tmpval == '100') || (tmpval == '200')  || (tmpval == '300') || (tmpval == '400') ){
        $('.copo100').addClass('copocheck');

    } else {

        $('.copo100').removeClass('copocheck');
    }

    if ((tmpval == '500') || (tmpval == '600')  || (tmpval == '700') || (tmpval == '800') || (tmpval == '900') ){
        $('.copo500').addClass('copocheck');

    } else {

        $('.copo500').removeClass('copocheck');
    }

    if ((tmpval > 999) ){
        $('.copo5001000').addClass('copocheck');

    } else {

        $('.copo5001000').removeClass('copocheck');
    }

});





$(function () {
    $('.add').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 50); }
             if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 99) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 100); }

    });
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 50);
        }
          if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 100) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 100);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.copocheck {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <div class="form-group spin">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-quantity">QUANTITY:</label>
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-default minus">-</button>
                         <input type="text" name="quantity" max="1000" value="0" size="2" id="troca" class="qty form-control" style="width: 60%;display: inline-block;"/>
  <button class="btn btn-default add" data-dir="up">+</button>
</p>



                      <div class="tabelas">
                        <table style=' font-family: Roboto Cn; font-size: 17px; width: 100%;' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' align='left'><tbody><tr class='cor copo50'><td>50&nbsp;Copos</td><td>R$ 2,00 <em>a unidade</em></td></tr><tr class='cor copo100'><td>100 - 400&nbsp;Copos</td><td>R$ 1,30 <em>a unidade</em></td><tr class='cor copo500'><td>500 - 900&nbsp;Copos</td><td>R$ 1,15 <em>a unidade</em></td></tr><tr class='cor copo5001000'><td>1000&nbsp;Copos</td><td>R$ 1,00&nbsp;<em>a unidade</em></td></tr></tbody></table>
                      </div>
```

Here it is as jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vh1Lcr3x/#

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the blur handler function in a separate function, and call that from the button click handler. When doing this, you've to get the reference to the input in a different way.

Comment: can show example ?

Comment: Just declare the current blur handler as a function, and assign `$('.qty').val()` to `tmpval`, then attach the function to the blur event like so:  `$('.qty').blur(THE_FUNCTION_NAME);`. Then call `THE_FUNCTION_NAME` from the button click handlers after changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

I can just give you the logic

Add an event listener for buttons using "ONE" instead of "ON" to make the value initially to zero.

Also add condition that it should work only if there is no value entered in the input field.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After click on `.add` and `.minus`, you have to execute the same code you're using when you're typing in `qty` field.

So, you can create a function like that :

```
function quantityUpdated()
{
    tmpval = $('.qty').val();

    $('.cor').removeClass('copocheck');

    if (tmpval == '50')
        $('.copo50').addClass('copocheck');

    if ((tmpval == '100') || (tmpval == '200')  || (tmpval == '300') || (tmpval == '400') )
        $('.copo100').addClass('copocheck');

    if ((tmpval == '500') || (tmpval == '600')  || (tmpval == '700') || (tmpval == '800') || (tmpval == '900') )
        $('.copo500').addClass('copocheck');

    if ((tmpval > 999) )
        $('.copo5001000').addClass('copocheck');
}
```

Then you use it like that :

```
$('.qty').blur(function() {
    quantityUpdated();
});

$('.add').on('click',function() {
    // You current code
    // [...]
    quantityUpdated();
});

$('.minus').on('click',function() {
    // You current code
    // [...]
    quantityUpdated();
});
```

PS : in `quantityUpdated()` you don't need to have many `removeClass`, just use one at the beginning and it will be added depending on quantity value with your tests.